# How android works if defining a service in manifest file without starting service in code

Tags: android

I find some android service example in github https://github.com/wildan2711/mqtt-android-tutorial. This is a demo project which is used to introduce how to use android mqtt library. In demo demo code,  the service is define

But this service is not started in the code. Why?

Comment: are you asking why someone implemented some code and then decide not to use it?

Comment: yes, because the document said this is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this service starting inside Library project. AFAIK it was necessary to declare service in Manifest of app using library as well. Now manifest merging will add service to app manifest automatically.

Comment: No, I didn't find the service process after app is started.

Comment: @richard inspect source code of library. why you decided it should start on app start